# Pdb's make my project always 'out of date'

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

My project is always out of date because of pdb's.
In VS output window i see always: 'Project is out of date. Input file foo.dll is older than output foo.pdb'. Always the same.
Why this happens? How i should fix that?

Comment: Did you compare the dates manually?

Comment: Dll is newer after build on some msecs

Comment: Have you done a clean and rebuild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i founded reason... It is because usage of assembly produced by project item in the project file:
If you in foo project file will define:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <ThisAssembly Include="$(TargetDir)\foo.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Than your project will always out of date:  Input file foo.dll is older than output foo.pdb... VS 2012 Sp2. That is sad.